# Which items from the Gun Mettle Cosmetic Case can be Unusual?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Earlier this week, the Gun Mettle Cosmetic Case had been released, which contains a selection of new cosmetics. There's also a chance that the item you get from it may be either Strange, Unusual or even both.

Earlier today, I managed to unbox an Unusual hat, and that was the Rotation Sensation.

**But what other items can be Unusual? Can all the items from the crate be Unusual, or only specific items from it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, in fact, only some specific items from the case can be unboxed. This is said by Bazaar.tf admin *buddhapest* [here](http://bazaar.tf/thread/7827/1/#post-111680), on a forum thread.

This is further proven by the [list of Unusual items](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Unusual#List_of_Unusual_items) on the wiki; the only items from the case that show up in this list are *hats* reather than all items there.

Answer (score 4):

The only items that the Gun Mettle Cosmetic Case are the ones listed in its description.  The last part of the case's description (in blue text) is:

> Contents may be Strange or an Unusual Gun Mettle Hat

Basically, this means that any Unusuals will be will be one of the hats already found in this case.  If you're super duper lucky, it'll be a Strange Unusual.

I'm not entirely sure if the skin rarity is also rolled for on unusuals.  If it is, then the Unusual Mercenary grade hats (which include the Rotation Sensation) will be more common than the Unusual Elite grade hats (which include the Potassium Bonnet).

Comment: Alright, but there's one last thing: is it only the hats, or every Cosmetic?

Comment: @Texenox The game no longer makes a distinction between Hats and Miscs.  Hats are just a cosmetic with the "hat" or "whole_head" equip region.